# Clarity involving Graph API Permissions

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions, access-token

Sorry.  Pretty new to this and trying to get a grasp on getting extended permissions/access_token for what I am trying to achieve.

All I need is to pull the public profile feed from someone's facebook page (returns in json format) so I can display it on said person's website. (I was going to parse this information using Jquery)

I think I understand that I will need to create an app in order to do this.  Now will I need to create an app from said person's facebook account?  Or is that something I can do myself, as a separate app?

Thanks for any info you can give on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could in do it from both.

However im not 100% certain on if you would need any extra permissions from the target user or not. Because it is a public feed I would think not, but I haven't tried this myself so I can say for certain.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for the response.  When trying to access the feed using graph.facebook.com/[id]/feed , I get a message saying I need authorization, even though the company page is completely public.  Or, if I just type in graph.facebook.com/[id] then I get a return of 'false'